# actionEventListener ("click") does not work after inserting another item

Tags: javascript, html, events, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add dynamically div elements inside `filtersSpace` div element and at the same time add an eventListener for each button inside the div elements but when I insert the second element the first one to be added does not work.

Can anybody help me ?

```
case "status":
        filtersSpace.innerHTML +=
            `<div class="card border-dark mx-2 my-3" style="width: 23%;">
                <h5 class="card-header">Status</h5>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <tr>
                        <select class="custom-select mr-sm-2" id="${'statusInput' + statusFilterCounter.toString(10)}">
                            <option selected value="Solved">Solved</option>
                            <option value="Open">Open</option>
                            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                        </select>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark my-2" style="width: 100%;"
                        id="${'statusActionButton' + statusFilterCounter.toString(10)}">
                            Filter
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark my-2" style="width: 100%;"
                        id="${'statusCancelButton' + statusFilterCounter.toString(10)}">
                            Cancel
                        </button>
                    </tr>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        defineFilter(
            "status",
            document.getElementById("statusInput" + statusFilterCounter.toString(10)),
            document.getElementById("statusActionButton" + statusFilterCounter.toString(10)),
            document.getElementById("statusCancelButton" + statusFilterCounter.toString(10))
        );
        statusFilterCounter += 1;
        statusLink.disabled = true;
        break;
```

...

```
function defineFilter(filterType, input, actionButton, cancelButton) {
actionButton.addEventListener("click",
    function () {
        filters.push({filterType : filterType, value : input.value});
        actionButton.disabled = true;
        print();
        getDataFromJSon();
    }
);
cancelButton.addEventListener("click",
    function () {
        var quantity = this.id.charAt(this.id.length - 1);
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++){
            if(filters[i].filterType == filterType){
                console.log(">>>");
                if(counter == quantity){
                    filters.splice(i, 1);
                    print();
                    getDataFromJSon();
                    break;
                }
                counter += 1;
            }
        }
        actionButton.disabled = false;
    }
);}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event` delegation for dynamically added elements.

See below how we use `e.target.matches([CSS Selector])` to decide what to do.

```js
const newAdd = () => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = `<button class='btn'>Click Me</button>`;
  document.querySelector('.container').appendChild(div);
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('.btn')) {
    console.log('I was clicked !!!');
  }
  
  if(e.target.matches('#add')) {
    newAdd();
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to register for the new element the event listener